# Query nested objects from MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssis, nested, bson

I created a script in SSIS to retrieve data from MongoDB.  While I don't have any issues querying regular documents, I am not sure how to retrieve values from nested documents.  For example, "Address" expanded contains "Country", "State", "City", "Street", and "Zip".  I am interested in retrieving the "Country" (field) values only.  In theory, I understand that it should be something like "Address.Country", but I do not know how to implement it in my code.  What is the best way to achieve that?

This is the code that retrieves all the other documents:

```
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
        MongoServer myMongo = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
        myMongo.Connect();
        var db = myMongo.GetDatabase("UserDB");
        /*ICursor<BsonDocument> cursor = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UserDB").FindAll();*/
        foreach (BsonDocument document in db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UserDB").FindAll())
        {
            this.UserDBBuffer.AddRow();
            this.UserDBBuffer.ID = document["_id"] == null ? "" : document["_id"].ToString();

            this.UserDBBuffer.PrimaryEmail = document["primary_email"] == null ? "" : document["primary_email"].ToString();
            this.UserDBBuffer.Gender = document["gender"] == null ? "" : document["gender"].ToString();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in C# using SetFields on the cursor returned by FindAll:

```
var fields = Fields.Include("Address.Country");
foreach (var document in collection.FindAll().SetFields(fields))
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
}
```

You can extract the Country value from the returned document using:

```
var country = document["Address"].AsBsonDocument["Country"].AsString;
```

Comment: Now, the next challenge is how to extract data from an array.  For example, one of the arrays looks like this: "devices -> Document -> device_data -> model" or "devices -> Document -> device_data -> brand".  How do I extract the model or the brand of the device?

Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I changed "Address" to "location" (another field containing country) and my scripts returns "country not found" and I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.find({_id: user_id},
              {'address.country': 1});
```

This will get you a document like

```
{"_id": ObjectId('4efb78234ee9184d8b5a4e92'), 
 "address": {"country": "Russia"}}
```